# Change dlls build path

Tags: c#, winforms

How can a change a dlls build path?

For example,

Current Location: MyApplication\Dll.dll

This is where I want the location to be: MyApplication\Dlls\Dll.dll

Is there any way I can achieve this

Comment: You can create a post build event to copy the resulting dll to another folder of your choice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776060/how-to-make-visual-studio-copy-a-dll-file-to-the-output-directory/1776094#1776094

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio, navigate to: Project > {project name} Properties > [Build Tab] > Output Path

Comment: I mean the dlls I want it to be separate from the application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029870/c-sharp-load-dll-from-different-folder